# TextInputLayout HelperText not changing color when activated

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have a TextInputLayout with the following theme:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutTheme" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

and helperTextTextAppearance:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutHelperText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.HelperText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/helper_text_color</item>
</style>
```

and the helper_text_color xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/grey" android:state_focused="false" />
</selector>
```

For the EditText and the hint text this works fine: It is grey and turns blue when I tap on the TIL and it is focused. 
 The helperText however stays grey all the time - I want it to change to blue also. 
I also tried to change it to `<item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_activated="true" />` but it's not working either.
How do I need to define the `helperTextTextAppearance` to make sure it changes it's color according to `colorControlActivated`?

Comment: Are you using the support design library or the material components library?

Comment: I'm using the design library.